# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/modulerr

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to inject an emoji app into my project.
I have added the [emoji.min.js](https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup/) and referenced it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/emoji.min.js"></script>
```

Now I am also injecting it into my project like this:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','ngSanitize','emojiApp'])
```

Immediately I inject the `emojiApp`, 
I get the following error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=ionicApp&p1=Error%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A115)

===================EDITTED=============

Completed injected file

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','LocalStorageModule','ngImgCrop', 'btford.socket-io', 'angularMoment','ngCordova','ngResource','ngSanitize','emojiApp'])
```

Complete script used in the index file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--    css scripting for fan page search-->
<!--<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
<!--cdn for isportline css fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<!--    for the ionic lightbox-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
<!--increase the height and the width of the ionic lightbox-->

<!-- Ionic framework - replace the CDN links with local files and build -->    

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/autocomplete.css">-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>-->


<!--fan page search resource-->
<!--  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular-resource.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/autocomplete.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-crop.js"></script>
<script src="js/loader-image.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

<script src="lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="lib/sio-client/socket.io.js"></script>

<script src="http://192.168.19.12:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>

<script src="js/services/SocketService.js"></script>

<script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/RoomController.js"></script>

<!-- emoticon scripting --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/emoji.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="css/emoji.min.css" />
```

Please what am I getting wrong. Kindly Assist!

Comment: may be u inject it before angular js files

Comment: emoji module is injected last

Comment: `emoji` has dependency on `jQuery` - have you included that?

Comment: I have included jQuery. Please check my edits

Comment: u must inject  it befor app.js

Comment: check ur grammatical expression

Comment: You mean in the app.js or index file?

Comment: It is emoji.min.js https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup/

Answer (score 0):

please try to add `<!-- emoticon scripting -->`
section before `<!--fan page search resource-->`

it may be version issue,
you added
`angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js` and `angular.js/1.3.7/angular-sanitize.min.js`

try to use same version

Comment: This is not a jsfiddle issue

Comment: Still thesame issues

Comment: Oh! is this happening because of `emoji`?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionicApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module emojiApp due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'spritesheetPath' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8100/js/emoji.min.js:3:593

Comment: it means `jQuery` called before `jquery sctipt`. please add `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>` on the top of page

Comment: `emojiApp` folder has correct file structure ? I mean images are at correct location

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionicApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module emojiApp due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'spritesheetPath' of undefined

Comment: please use `emoji`'s `dist` folder